# How do I remove float left for responsive web development

Tags: html, css

Currently at full size I have my nav bar set up in horizontal manner.
I achieved it  by using float left.

Now I am trying to make responsive website and how do I remove float left so it would be back to horizontal again?

Comment: Please provide your code or create a fiddle for the issue.

Comment: Add some code so it is easy for people to help you!!

Comment: I find your lack of code distributing.  Make an [edit] to show some effort.

Answer (score 3):

You could use media queries to set your responsive widths. When the screen is under your desired screen width, change the float. See example below:

```
nav { float: left; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    nav { float: none; }
}
```

More info on media queries can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp